# How can I perform a case sensitive git rm -r?

Tags: git, version-control

I accidentally created my App/ directory with and uppercase 'A', committed my change, and realized I wanted it to be a lowercase 'a' to match my other top level directory names.

I followed the advice of another stackoverflow post and set git to be case insensitive by executing the following command:

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```

However, if I now perform

```
git rm -r App
```

it deletes some files from my app/ directory as well. I would like to know if there's a way I can remove this duplicate App/ directory from git without deleting anything from app/.

Comment: Why don't you just rename? `git mv App app`?

Answer (score 6):

Create a new directory name `app`

- `git mv App/* app/`

It move all the content of `App` directory into `app`. After that you can delete `App` directory.

**Edit** : As you mentioned in comment section of this answer that, you have renamed the folder.

- `git rm -r --cached .`
- `git add -A`
- `git commit -m "Suitable Message"`

Comment: This is probably just me being stupid, but the way I changed its name to app was to right click > refactor > rename. So now when I try to run the above command I get fatal: cannot move directory over file, source=App/Controllers, destination=app/Controllers

Comment: @Robert : what is the output of `git status`  ?

Comment: not sure if it will help, but the output is Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

        modified:   public/src/External/intro.js (modified content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Comment: @Robert : I have updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: that did it! I guess what I was looking for is git rm --cached thank you.

Comment: @Robert : It should be recursive. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I've had a similar issue when working on both Windows and Mac. In my situation, I cloned my repo with the duplicate folders and only one was pulled (the unwanted, uppercase). My lowercase folder had the same contents on the repo, but wasn't pulled.

I simply used the first command: `git mv src/Folder* src/folder`, made a commit, checked out code again ... then all was well in the world again.